# magento2 calendar validate error?

Tags: magento2, validation

Have a good date.
I tried create form in frontend magento2.

```
<form data-hasrequired="* Required Fields" method="post" id="contact-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
 ...
     <input type="date" value="04-07-2016" class="type-date" max="19-07-2016" min="19-06-2016" id="okes" name="date-854" aria-invalid="true">
  ...
</form>
    <script>
     require(["jquery", "jquery/ui", "mage/calendar", "mage/validation"],
     function($){
        $("input[type=date]").each(function(){
           var min = $(this).attr('min'),
               max = $(this).attr('max'), minDate = maxDate = "";
               if(typeof min !== typeof undefined && min !== false ){
                 minDate = new Date(min.replace( /(\d{2})[-/](\d{2})[-/](\d+)/, "$2,$1,$3") );
               }
               if(typeof max !== typeof undefined && max !== false ){
                 maxDate = new Date(max.replace( /(\d{2})[-/](\d{2})[-/](\d+)/, "$2,$1,$3") );
               }
               //alert(minDate);
           $(this).calendar({
               showsTime: false,
                buttonText:"<?php echo __('Select Date') ?>",
                minDate: minDate,
                maxDate: maxDate,
                dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
             });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

when i submit form error in input type=date. It not show error.
Please tell me  this code what's wrong? Many thank.

this image 
[image]

Comment: are you want to check valid date?

Comment: yes i want check validate use to "mage/calendar", "mage/validation" in magento2.

Answer (score 1):

add `"validate-date"` class in your input field to validate date.

You can also use `"validate-date-range"` class for check max date.

Comment: thank you answer my question? I tried it but not success.

Comment: try with apply type="text"

Comment: if i set type text. code in <script> tag 
not use to be.

Comment: you can apply any perticular class and use $(".any_class") in <script> tag.

Comment: hi. I tried it but it not work. :(

Comment: can you please provide new code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42748/discussion-between-xanka-and-jaimin-parikh).